# printf statement including quotes and escape sequence

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble making a print statement that includes quotes and a new line escape sequence. I tried to use \n for a new line and backslash before open quote and before closing quotes to tell my program to include the quotations. I don't know where I went wrong and I keep getting an error in my int main(void) line (sorry if I'm not using correct terminology, I'm in an intro c MOOC).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Dennis Ritchie said:\n\"The only way to learn a new programming language is by writing programs in it.\");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the final close-string dblquote. That is literally the only thing wrong with this code. The end should look like `it.\"");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only missing closing `"` and `\n` for readability:

```
printf("Dennis Ritchie said:\n\"The only way to learn a new programming language is by writing programs in it.\"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the closing quote

```
 printf("Dennis Ritchie said:\n\"The only way to learn a new programming language is by writing programs in it.\"");
```